# Is it possible to perform 32-bit bitwise operation on a 4 elements unsigned char array in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, rotation, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a C program to rotate a word inside a unsigned char array of 4 elements.
Each array is organized inside a `uint8_t` 4x4 matrix, and the user would type in some text, which would get stored inside this matrix and then a function would be called to rotate the text stored in a specific row using the following operation:

`wordBuffer[row][0] = (wordBuffer[row][0] >> 8) | (wordBuffer[row][0] << 24)`

I am aware that if I pass a pointer of an `uint8_t` matrix to the function I would be performing this operation on a 8-bit variable instead on the 32 bits stored at the 4 elements row. To access further memory positions I declared `uint32_t` pointer and typecast the desired address like below:

`uint32_t (*pointerToWord)[4] = (uint32_t*)(&wordBuffer[row][0]);`

For the first row (0th row), it works like I expected, my terminal window returns:

```
Type in some text: ABCD

Data from row 0: BCDA
Data from row 1:
Data from row 2:
Data from row 3:
```

However to further rows this seems to not be the case, like for the second or further rows:

```
Type in some text: ABCD

Data from row 0:
Data from row 1: ABCD
Data from row 2:
Data from row 3:
```

My question regarding this matter is: If it is possible to perform the word rotation using the bitwise operation on this case or should I rely on some other method?

I thank you all in advance for reading and looking further into my question!

Best Wishes!

Below there are the code snippets I wrote and the compiler I am using:

***main.c***

```
int main(void)
{
    system("cls");

    uint8_t wordBuffer[N_ROWS][R_LENGTH] = {'0'};
    uint8_t row = 1;
    uint32_t (*pointerToWord)[R_LENGTH] = (uint32_t*)(&wordBuffer[row][0]);   

    printf("Type in some text: ");
    scanf("%s", &wordBuffer[row]);

    DEBUG_FUNCTION_001(wordBuffer, row, pointerToWord);
    
    return 0;
}
```

***functions.c***

```
static void rotate32BitWord(uint32_t (*pointerToWord)[R_LENGTH], uint8_t row)
{   
    /* Rotate 32-Bit Word inside Buffer
    *   @param wordBuffer   Memory buffer containing word
    *   @param row          Desired row to rotate
    * */

   pointerToWord[row][0] = (pointerToWord[row][0] >> 8) | (pointerToWord[row][0] << 24);
   
}

static void printDataFromBuffer(uint8_t (*wordBuffer)[R_LENGTH], uint8_t row)
{
    /* Prints word stored in buffer
    *  @param wordBuffer   Memory buffer containing word
    *  @param row          Desired row to print data
    * */

    printf("\n");
    for (row = 0; row < N_ROWS; row++)
    {
        printf("Data from row %d: %s\n", row, wordBuffer[row]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
}

void DEBUG_FUNCTION_001
(   
    uint8_t (*wordBuffer)[R_LENGTH], 
    uint8_t row, 
    uint32_t (*pointerToWord)[R_LENGTH]
)
{
    rotate32BitWord(pointerToWord, row);
    printDataFromBuffer(wordBuffer, row);    
}
```

***resources.h***

```
#ifndef RESOURCES_H_
#define RESOURCES_H_

/* Standard C */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Macros */
#define N_ROWS      4   // Number of Rows
#define R_LENGTH    4   // Length of Rows

/* function prototypes */

void DEBUG_FUNCTION_001
(   
    uint8_t (*wordBuffer)[R_LENGTH], 
    uint8_t row, 
    uint32_t (*pointerToWord)[R_LENGTH]
);

#endif /* RESOURCES_H_ */
```

***Compiler***

```
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: You are indexing into the array twice: `main` sets `pointerToWord` to point to `wordbuffer[row]`, and then `rotate32BitWord` indexes it again, as `pointerToWord[row]`. So it operates on row 2 instead of row 1. Filling the entire array with recognizable data (such as letters “a” through “p”) and then printing the data as you operated on it would have revealed this quickly.

Comment: `printDataFromBuffer` should limit what it is going to print. `wordBuffer` is not guarantee to be null terminated, so `%s` should not be used with it. `%.4s` would limit printing to four characters.

Comment: That said, never cast an array declared as `uint8_t` to `uint32_t`. The cast may fail due to alignment issues, and, even if it does not, accessing elements defined as `uint8_t` elements with a `uint32_t` lvalue violates the aliasing rule in the C standard.  A proper way to do this is to define the array originally as an array of `uint32_t`. Then you are allowed to alias the individual bytes using character types (because character types are special for this in C), and you can still use `uint32_t` operations on the elements, because that is what they are actually defined as.

Comment: Actually, the indexing is worse than I thought. `pointerToWord` is a pointer to an array of four `uint32_t`. That means it points to something 16 bytes long, and that means `pointerToWord[1]` points to something 16 bytes beyond row 1 of `wordBuffer`, which is outside the array entirely. To use and pass a pointer to a `uint32_t`, just declare a pointer to a `uint32_t`. There is no need to be fancy with pointers to arrays.

Comment: Thank you kindly Eric, you clarified a lot of my doubts. 
If I were to access individual characters contained inside the `uint32_t` array would I need perform a bitwise AND between a 4 Byte bitmask and the array's indexed element?

Comment: Character types are special; you can always access (read or write) the data of an object using a character type (`char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`). To be paranoically safe, you should use `unsigned char`. Generally, a C implementation will define `uint8_t` to be `unsigned char` (or maybe `char` if it is unsigned), and then it would be okay to use `uint8_t` to access the bytes of an object. However, an implementation could also define an “extended” type that is the same as `unsigned char` except it is not special for accessing object data, and then it could define `uint8_t` to be that.